# Razor is shown as plain text in visual studio 2022

Tags: c#, html, razor, visual-studio-2022

I started experimenting with blazor in visual studio 2022. But it seems that vs sees the text (except for the html) as plain text. Just white plain text, and when I go to fonts and colors, it changes when I change the color of the plain text.

What is wrong?

Next to that, the functionalities doesn't seem to work as well

Comment: Can You share the code?

Comment: Make sure that the C# code is wrapped inside @code{} or have @ at the front of the 
 C# code block

Comment: If I try to upload a screenshot I get a error message from stack overflow: Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server"

I am following a tutorial from microsoft learn: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/blazor-build-rich-interactive-components

The code works but visual studio is just ..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.